# "Why do you not give" Vs "Why do not you give"

Tags: negation, interrogatives, contractions, subject-auxiliary-inversion, wh-questions

Are they, both sentences, grammatically and semantically acceptable?

> - Why ***do*** ***you*** ***not*** give him your flesh and your bones?
> - Why ***do*** ***not*** ***you*** give him your flesh and your bones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very simple example of ***subject–auxiliary inversion***, and it is required in most interrogative sentences in English. The subject and the auxiliary verb appear in the reverse of the order in which they would appear in a declarative.

Consider the following declarative version of your interrogative:

> You<sup><sup>SUBJECT</sup></sup> do<sup><sup>AUXILIARY</sup></sup> not<sup><sup>NEGATIVE</sup></sup> give him your flesh and your bones.

In your interrogative version, the presence of the auxiliary verb *do* causes subject–auxiliary inversion to take place. In negated questions like this one, the negating word *not* should appear after the subject, not after the auxiliary:

> Why do<sup><sup>AUXILIARY</sup></sup> you<sup><sup>SUBJECT</sup></sup> not<sup><sup>NEGATIVE</sup></sup> give him your flesh and your bones?

Note that the negating word can also appear attached to the auxiliary in the form of the contraction *don't*:

> Why don't <sup><sup>AUXILIARY + NEGATIVE</sup></sup> you<sup><sup>SUBJECT</sup></sup> give him your flesh and your bones?

Answer (score 1):

Only the first one is grammatically acceptable.

To clear up some potential confusion, here's a clarification on contracted and non-contracted sentence structure.  Here is the sentence with a contraction:

> Why **don't** you give him your flesh and your bones?

while this is not contracted:

> Why **do** you **not** give him your flesh and your bones?

however, it is ***not*** this:

> Why **do not** you...

**Don't** contracts the **do** and **not**, and even though the shortened words appear next to each other when contracted, the subject of the sentence (in this case, **you**) must go between the **do** and **not**.

Comment: such a simple and clear answer, why has no one up voted it?